# Initialize weights and bias in torch

Tags: keras, pytorch, torch

What is the equivalent command for the below keras code in Pytorch

```
Dense(64, kernel_initializer='he_normal', bias_initializer='zeros', name='uhat_digitcaps')(d5)
```

How to I initialize weights and bias?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_channels, 64)
        nn.init.kaiming_normal_(self.linear.weight, mode='fan_out')
        nn.init.constant_(self.linear.bias, 0)
```